# Como fazer com que o CSS ignore se o atributo está com letra MAIÚSCULA ou minúscula?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Imagine que eu tenha uma situação onde eu precise estilizar vários links da minha página, mas só os links que terminem em `.html`, porém reparei que ao tentar pegar o atributo `href`, eu só consigo pegar os que terminam exatamente com `.html`, se for `.HTML` ou `.Html` por exemplo o link não pega o estilo. Eu não gostaria que esse acontecesse, eu quero pegar o link independente se está ou não com letra maiúscula.

Exite alguma forma de corrigir isso? Fazer com que o CSS ignore se o atributo está com letra MAIÚSCULA ou minúscula?

Segue um exemplo do problema:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all ease-out .2s;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

[href*="html"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="pagina.HTML">link terminando em .HTML</a>
<a href="pagina.html">link terminando em .html</a>
<a href="pagina.Html">link terminando em .Html</a>
```

Comment: Mais uma vez uma excelente pergunta e mais uma vez aprendi algo novo pesquisando sobre. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

O [seletor CSS de atributos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) segue o padrão:

```
[atributo operador valor i]
```

Onde:

1. **`atributo`**: é o atributo HTML do elemento
2. **`operador`**: é operador utilizado na comparação entre `valor` e o conteúdo do atributo no elemento. Os operadores podem ser:

   - **`=`**: quando `valor` é **exatamente igual** ao conteúdo do atributo;

     ```
     a[href="#"]{}
     /* Casa com todos os links que `href` sejam exatemente "#" */
     ```
   - **`~=`**: quando o conteúdo do atributo é uma **lista separada por espaços em branco** e `valor` é um **elemento desta lista**;

     ```
     button[class~="is-small"]{}
     /* Casa com:
         <button class="button is-small is-primary"></button>
         <button class="button is-active is-small"></button>
         <button class="is-small button"></button>
         <button class="is-small"></button>

        NÃO casa com:
         <button class="is-small-extra"></button>
         <button class="really-is-small"></button>
     */
     ```
   - **`|=`**: quando o conteúdo do atributo é **exatamente igual** ao `valor` ou **começa com `valor` seguido de hífen**;

     ```
     html[lang|="en"]{}
     /* Casa com:
          <html lang="en"></html>
          <html lang="en-US"></html>
          <html lang="en-GB"></html>
     */
     ```
   - **`^=`**: quando o conteúdo do atributo **começa com `valor`**;

     ```
     a[href^="#"]{}
     /* Casa com:
          <a href="#">
          <a href="#top">
          <a href="#modal">
     */
     ```
   - **`$=`**: quando o conteúdo do atributo **termina com `valor`**;

     ```
     a[href$=".html"]{}
     /* Casa com:
          <a href="/index.html">
          <a href="/header.html">
     */
     ```
   - **`*=`**: quando o conteúdo do atributo **contém `valor`** como substring;

     ```
     a[href*=".htm"]{}
     /* Casa com:
          <a href="/index.html">
          <a href="/page.htm">
          <a href="/abc.htmdef/index.cgi">
     */
     ```

3. **`valor`**: é uma string que será comparada com o conteúdo do atributo
4. **`i`**: é uma *flag* opcional que indican se é a comparação será [*ascii case insensitive*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/infrastructure.html#ascii-case-insensitive) (apenas caractéres entre `a` e `z` não acentuados serão *case insensitive*).

Então para casar com qualquer link cujo `href` termine com `.html` você faria:

```
a[href$=".html"]
```

Porém não funcionará com `.Html`, `.HTML`, `.HtMl`, etc…
Para isso basta adicionar a flag `i`:

```
a[href$=".html" i]
```

O exemplo acima casará corretamente com as variações possíveis de caixa alta.

Vale lembra que a regra:

```
a[href$=".abc" i]
```

Casará com `.ABC`, `.AbC`, mas **não funcionará** com `.Ábc`, ou `.äBc` por ser 
[*ascii case insensitive*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/infrastructure.html#ascii-case-insensitive).

> **[EDIT]** A flag `s` também faz parte da spec e, ao contrário da `i`, força a comparação a ser *ascii case sensitive*.

---

### Specs

Após uma boa pesquisa por várias versões e drafts acabei descobrindo que a *flag* `i` no seletor de atributos faz parte do [draft do módulo de seletores](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#attribute-case), que por ser um trabalho em andamento, seu suporte ainda não é completo.

Porém, com exceção do **Internet Explorer, Microsoft Edge e Opera Mini**, os browser modernos já suportam esta feature, como mostrado no [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-case-insensitive).

Vendo a [versão 3 dos seletores CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors) temos:

> Attribute values must be CSS identifiers or strings. The case-sensitivity of attribute names and values in selectors depends on the document language.

Que em tradução livre significa:

> Valores de atributos devem ser identificadores CSS ou strings. O *case-sensitivity* dos nomes de atributos e dos valores nos seletores dependem da linguagem do documento.

Como nosso documento é HTML,  na sessão de [*Case-Sensitivity* e Comparação de Strings](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/infrastructure.html#case-sensitivity-and-string-comparison) da versão 5.2 temos:

> Except where otherwise stated, string comparisons must be performed in a case-sensitive manner.

Em tradução livre:

> A menos que especificado o contrário, comparações de strings devem ser feitas de maneira *case-sensitive*.

E como não há especificação no spec atual, isso explicaria o porquê de ser *case-sensitive* por padrão nos navegadores.

---

### Código

```css
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all ease-out .2s;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

[href*="html" i] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="pagina.HTML">link terminando em .HTML</a>
<a href="pagina.html">link terminando em .html</a>
<a href="pagina.Html">link terminando em .Html</a>
```

Comment: Show, não sabia dessa. Irei deixar minha resposta apenas como alternativa para futuras pesquisas. +1

Comment: Muito bom jovem é isso mesmo! Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Saberia informar se isso é previsto pelo W3C/WHATWG? O único lugar que encontrei sobre foi esta documentação na MDN que também citou. Com isso em mente, sabe se funciona em todos os navegadores da mesma forma? Além disso, a documentação MDN cita que o `i` funciona apenas para caracteres ASCII, o que seria interessante adicionar na resposta, visto que `fóo` seria diferente de `foo` mesmo com o a *flag*.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss obrigado pela sugestão. Editei a resposta. Qualquer recomendação é só avisar. Valeu.

Comment: Algum motivo específico para o -1? Se puder me informar para eu melhorar a resposta seria útil...

Answer (score 0):

Apenas com `CSS` não sei se é possível fazer, mas criei uma solução usando `jquery`. Não sei se é o que estas a buscar, é apenas uma ideia de como poderia ser feito.

Deixei o código todo comentado, caso tenha dúvidas, pergunte.

```js
$('a').each(function(){ //para cada link
   var attr = $(this).attr('href'); //pega o atributo
   var lower = attr.toLowerCase(); // transforma todos em minusculo 
   var html = lower.indexOf('.html'); //pega todos link que contem .html
   
   if(html != -1) { // aplica a todos links que tiverem .html
      $(this).css('color', 'green')
   }   
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all ease-out .2s;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="pagina.HTML">link terminando em .HTML</a>
<a href="pagina.html">link terminando em .html</a>
<a href="pagina.Html">link terminando em .Html</a>
<a href="pagina.Htmlx">link terminando em .Htmlx</a>
<a href="pagina.xml">link terminando em .xml</a>
```

Comment: Valeu jovem, mas com CSS resolvi dessa vez

Comment: Sim... Deixarei a resposta apenas como segunda opção para futuras consultas.

Comment: Você consegue fazer isso apenas com JavaScript *vanilla*, sem jQuery, de maneira bem simples: http://jsfiddle.net/acwoss/7nL4qcko/3/