# Como estilizar classes iniciadas com .fa-?

Tags: css

Estou usando o **FontAwesome** no **React** e para alterar a cor de um icone é necessário alterar a cor na classe do icone. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
.fa-drash{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

A baixo segue a forma como está hoje, porém toda vez que incluo um novo icone na aplicação, tenho que atualizar a folha de estilo.

```
.fa-drash, fa-ed, .fa-adjust, .fa-acorn, .fa-alarm, .fa-amazon, .fa-apple, .fa-appter{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Meu pensamento seria melhorar isso inserindo apenas as iniciais da classe `.fa-`, como por exemplo abaixo, porém não funcionou comigo:

```
.fa-*{
     color: #ff0000;
}
```

É possível estilizar classes iniciadas com `.fa-`? Sim sim, como?

Comment: Eu não recomendo estilizar diretamente a classe "fa".
Aconselharia você criar uma classe sua, por exemplo "my-icon" e estilizar ela com suas configurações "padrões". A medida do necessário, você apenas atribui essa nova classe aos ícones que você deseja que herde essas propriedades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concordo com o @Anderson, mas tem uma forma sim de pegar todas as classes que começam ou tenha dentro com determinado algum determinado nome ou caractere como por exemplo o `"fa-"`...

Resumidamente vc vai fazer a seleção pelo atributo `class` usando o *operador* `*` antes do `=`, assim toda class que tenha dentro do nome qualquer string que contenha `"fa-"` vai ser selecionada.

> **`[attr*=value]`** Representa um elemento com um atributo de nome `attr` o qual valor contém ao menos uma ocorrência de value contido na string.

Fonte com a lista completa dos *operadores*  `~ | ^ $ *` e como cada um dele funciona: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Seletor_de_atributos

```css
[class*="fa-"] {
    color:red;
    font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i>
</div>

<p>
  <i class="fab fa-angellist"></i>
</p>
```

---

**DICA:**

Isso `[href*="html"]` é diferente disso `[href*="HTML"]`

O CSS é *`case sensitive`* e para evitar problemas com *CamelCase* ou Caixa Alta vc coloca no final do seletor a letra **`i`**

```
[attr operator value i]
```

Adiciona um `i` (ou `I`) antes do fechamento das chaves `{}`, faz com que o valor seja comparado sem levar em conta caixa alta ou caixa baixa(para caracteres dentro da faixa ASCII).

Aqui nessa pergunta tem uns detalhes sobre o assunto: [Como fazer com que o CSS ignore se o atributo está com letra MAIÚSCULA ou minúscula?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/330101/como-fazer-com-que-o-css-ignore-se-o-atributo-est%C3%A1-com-letra-mai%C3%9Ascula-ou-min%C3%BAsc)

Comment: Boa resposta Hugo. Vlw.

Comment: @Viana Sem problemas meu caro. Esse técnica serve para qq atributo, vc pode pegar por exemplo todos IDs que tenha alguma palavra, ou todos elementos que tenha um `[data-text]` e por ai vai! []´s

Answer (score 2):

Nao seria mas pratico se vc criar uma classe secudaria com a cor que vc quer? assim vc pode fazer reutilizar sem precisar refazer a css da fontawesome.

```css
.fa-vermelho{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fas fa-igloo fa-vermelho"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mas por que precisa alterar a cor da fonte direto no ícone? Basta você alterar no contexto que o ícone se encontra.

```css
body {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

div {
  color: green;
}

p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i>
</div>

<p>
  <i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i>
</p>
```

Comment: Obrigado Anderson pela sugestão e resposta, mas não responde exatamente a pergunta. Mas acho que daria para melhorar respondendo de fato o que eu perguntei e deixando sua resposta como incremento. Eu não encontrei em documentações de folha de estilo se isso é possível.